# How to check if a URL string contains either of 2 substrings?

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a string contains either one of 2 other strings? For example, I want to check if a `URL` contains either one of these string `localhost` or `10.0.2.2`

```
http://localhost:5000 -> true
10.0.2.2:5000 -> true
dasdasdasdasdlocalhostdasdasd -> true
dasdasdasd10.0.2.2:5000dasdasd -> true
http://example.com -> false
```

Comment: `"test".includes("localhost") || "test".includes("10.0.2.2")`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/localhost|10.0.2.2/.test(URL)) {
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.some()` to determine if a string contains some of the keywords.

```js
const urls = ['10.0.2.2:5000', 'dasdasdasdasdlocalhostdasdasd', 'dasdasdasd10.0.2.2:5000dasdasd', 'http://example.com'];

const keywords = ['localhost', '10.0.2.2'];

const urlsWithKeywords = urls.filter(url => {
  return keywords.some(keyword => url.includes(keyword));
});

console.log(urlsWithKeywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = /localhost|10.0.2.2/;
var url= "your url here";

if (pattern.test(url)) {
    // That means return true
   //your rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers